# modifying php-imap extension to allow oauth authentication

Tags: php, c, oauth, imap, php-extension

My php application logs into to Gmail via oauth provided access keys and fetch headers for all messages in inbox. The php-imap extension allows only for login/password based authentication. I want to modify the extension so that it support oauth based authentication too. I need to figure out how to make that change inside the extension code itself and compile it. Bad part, I do not have much clue where to make changes and how to compile a php extension

Earlier I was using the Zend provided IMAP classes for this task. They are very slow and gmail tends to disconnect the connection if it takes more than 40-45 minutes or so. For very large inboxes this was happening frequently. I tested this with php-imap extension and it worked almost 10 times faster that the zend one (i guess since its written in C)

So I need to figure out how and where authentication is taking place in the current php-imap code and how do i re-compile it after making the changes.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

PHP wraps the [c-client](http://www.washington.edu/imap/) libary, so the first thing you would have to check would be if there's a way to use OAuth authentication with that library. You may try [this mailing list](http://www.washington.edu/imap/lists/imap-uw.html).

The PHP extension is implemented in just [one file](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/imap/php_imap.c?revision=298625&view=markup). You won't have trouble finding out where the connection/authentication takes place.

Comment: thanks. I've already started looking into c-client library. Hopefully I'll be able to figure out something with some more effort. btw that mailing list is receive only. only subscribed users can send.

Comment: This is a FULL implementation of standard PHP IMAP functions like (imap_open, imap_getmailboxes, imap_*, etc...) https://github.com/ddeboer/imap/issues/443#issuecomment-1172158902 @Nands

Answer (score 0):

Using php_sockets Implemented a simple library. Hopefully will act as required.
Delete mail function is not yet added. But you can take a look if it satisfies your need.

Try example. https://github.com/vmuthal/VivOAuthIMAP